# Minimising integrals with respect to limits?

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have been reading a paper where there is the following objective function to be minimised by choosing $s$:

$\displaystyle \alpha \int_{s}^{1} t(s_{2}) g(s_{1}+s_{2})ds_{2} + \alpha \int_{0}^{s} t(s)g(s_{1}+s_{2})ds_{2}+\int_{0}^{s}(s_{2}-\frac{s}{2})^{2}ds_{2}$

The first order condition that the paper arrives at is

$\displaystyle t'(s)\alpha[G(s_{1}+s)-G(s_{1})]+\frac{s^2}{4}=0$

where $s_{1}, s_{2} \in [0, 1]$ are constants and $G(x)=\int_{0}^{x} g(y)dy$. $\alpha$ is also a constant and $g(\bullet)$ is a strictly convex arbitrary function. 
An application of the fundamental theorem of calculus would not produce $t'(s)$ or $G(\bullet)$. I have also tried using integration by parts but I arrive at the same expression as when I used the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Any ideas on how the FOC is derived? There are a number of other similar first order conditions that are in a similar form, so I am hoping that by understanding this derivation, it will help me understand the rest of the paper. Thanks

Comment: But that's surely an application of the fundamental theorem of calculus. Maybe there's a computational mistake. Are you sure you are applying [Leibniz's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) properly?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro thank you for your comment. I'm not sure how Leibniz would apply to the first integral, as it is not a function of $s$. Perhaps it does involve the fundamental theorem of calculus and I am not applying it properly?

Comment: Yes the first one is $t_{s_{2}}$ and the second one is $t_{s}$. This is from Gul, Faruk, and Russell Lundholm. “Endogenous Timing and the Clustering of Agents' Decisions.” Journal of Political Economy, vol. 103, no. 5, 1995, pp. 1039–1066 at page 1059 of http://www.jstor.org/stable/2138754

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is correct. Here's how I computed it: 
$$
\frac{d}{ds} \int_s^1 t(s_2)g(s_1+s_2)\, ds_2 =-t(s)g(s_1+s).$$
Moreover,
$$
\frac{d}{ds}\int_0^s t(s)g(s_1+s_2)\,ds_2=t'(s)\int_0^s g(s_1+s_2)\, ds_2 + t(s)g(s_1+s), $$ 
and finally 
$$
\frac{d}{ds} \int_0^s(s_2-\frac{s}2)^2\, ds_2 = \frac{s^2}{4}.$$ 
When you multiply the first two by $\alpha$ and sum, the term $t(s)g(s_1+s)$ cancels out. And notice that 
$$\int_0^s g(s_1+s_2)\, ds_2= G(s_1+s)-G(s_1).$$

Comment: Thank you @Giuseppe Negro. I understand that the first line is simply applying the fundamental theorem of calculus to the limits of the integral. How did you get the $t'(s)$ out of the second line? I'm not sure how that transformation works.

Comment: Just take it out of the integration sign. $\int_a^b t(s) \text{something}(s_2)\, ds_2=t(s)\int_a^b\text{something}(s_2)\, ds_2.$